# x, y direction to degree

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have a tuple `(x, y)` with `x` and `y` in [-1, 1]. The tuple represents a movement in any direction. I would like to convert this to a 360 degree angle, where 0 represents north.

Comment: atan, does only span 0 - 90 degree angle or equivalently works only an x and y element of [0, 1].

Comment: Lev, of course I have trouble with the math and not a two statement programming task.

Comment: Davoud the reason you were asked about whether it was the math or the programming you had trouble with because you said "I would particularly like a solution in Python".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on what 'North' means, i.e. along which axis, and what direction the angles are supposed to go, the following code should be a solution to your problem:

```
 math.atan2(y,x)/math.pi*180
```

This gives you the angle of a point(x,y) from the origin, counter-clockwise with 'North' along the x-axis.

Comment: There's the `degree` function in math module, to convert between radians and degrees

Comment: note, this gives -180 to 180, you may need to rotate your x and y, and add 180 if you want 0-360

Answer (score 7):

I won't give you a solution, but I will point you in the right direction.  Most programming languages have a function called `atan2`, which takes an x and y value as input and calculates  the angle in radians between the point and the positive x axis.  It automatically takes care of quadrant issues.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Thanks, the solution is simply `math.atan2(x, y)` the solution in in radians.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Keep in mind, with `math.atan2`, 0 represents east.  If this was the best answer, don't forget to accept!

Answer (score 3):

The mathematics is as follows.

tan = opposite/adjacent.  (y and x respectively in your case).

arctan(r) = angle, given ratio r of opposite to adjacent.

arctan2 is like arctan but takes care of quadrant issues.

I should add that this is all for right-angled triangles.

*The rigorous definition of Atan2, taken from wikipedia*:

[image]

You can find more information here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctan2

Answer (score 1):

This can also be generically done for any two points forming a segment:

```
segment = ((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

from math import *

angle = degrees(atan((x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)))
```

Just remember to check for quadrant issues

Comment: In his case, one coordinate is (0,0).

Comment: You're right, I think `atan2` is right, as suggested by crazedgremlin.

Comment: atan, does only span 0 - 90 degree angle or equivalently works only an x and y element of [0, 1].